# Visual Studio 2019, CMake, Drivers and clang. Deploying?

Tags: visual-studio, cmake, kernel, clang

Old project uses VS2019, MSVC and standard visual studio project files, to compile a kernel driver - after which I can hit F5 to deploy the driver to a 2nd VM running same version of Windows, to test my code - and debug.

Starting the port all again, to fit better with upstream. I wanted to attempt to use clang (visual studio installer, tick clang support), and CMakelists.txt. (I open Folder containing Cmakelists.txt). It will be easier for upstream.

I have it compiling the .SYS file with clang (some massaging needed around intrin.h) but have heard that drivers can not be compiled with clang? Yes/no?

(But as a work around, I could compile most with clang into a .lib, then finish off with MSVC++).

Either way, is it at all possible to make Visual Studio using CMake to "deploy" to the 2nd VM and debug? If not, can I work around that by making a lean project file with just the produced binary .sys file to deploy?

Comment: AFAIK, Driver can't be compiled with clang only with MSVC.

Answer (score 0):

Having this discussion at work there should be no reason UMDs (user mode drivers) can't be compiled with clang-cl/clang.

However I don't believe you can yet compile kernel mode drivers with clang.

The main flag that makes this possible is "/DRIVER":

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/driver-windows-nt-kernel-mode-driver?view=msvc-160

And clang-cl doesn't support that yet:

https://clang.llvm.org/docs/UsersManual.html#clang-cl

Perhaps consider filing a ticket for /DRIVER support from clang-cl?

Comment: Yes, that seems to be the case. So, it turns out that if I run:
```
cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=x64-Debug -G "Visual Studio 16" -A x64 -B contrib/windows  -T ClangCL -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER="C:/Program Files/LLVM/bin/clang-cl.exe" -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER="C:/Program Files/LLVM/bin/clang-cl.exe"
```
Cmake will spit out project files, and I can use VC to deploy and debug. I think I just wasn't holding the tool the right way.

Now, I was hoping that I can pick clang-cl for wdk_add_library, then just use MSVC to compile `driver.c` and link with libraries. Should get me around the missing driver feature